# Why does Word not like this statement, "For each iteration"

Tags: grammar

Every time I type "after each iteration", Word tells me it has an issue with it. The specific issue is "Number agreement". What am I missing?

My text is "XYZ must occur after each iteration."

Comment: The issue here is that, for several reasons, it's basically impossible to program a grammar checker that can accurately decide whether any given sentence is grammatically correct.  If you're going to use Word's grammar checker, you have to be prepared to take its output with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Iteration* may be used as a countable or uncountable noun.

> XYZ must occur after each iteration

is correct if *iteration* is used as a countable noun. Word may have taken it to be solely uncountable. For example,

> Iteration is needed to calculate this number. (uncountable)
>
> Five iterations are needed to calculate this number. (countable)

Comment: So basically I'll have to change to a different word instead of "iteration" if I want to avoid Word yelling at me?

Comment: @DustinDavis: No, just turn off that rule. Or turn off grammar checking altogether.

Comment: Or stop trusting man made machines:)